# Как выводить placeholder только один раз при загрузке?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Задача в том чтобы при загрузке страницы `placeholder` в `input` выводился, но когда пользователь что-то начал печатать и стёр то что напечатал, `placeholder` обратно не возвращался т.е `input` оставался пустым?! Как реализовать?

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Впишите тут текст"/>
```

Comment: Попробуйте javascript....

Answer (score 2):

что нибудь типа:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.placeholder=''" placeholder="Впишите тут текст"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы инлайново каждый раз не писать, можно повесить обработчик через js на все элементы, у которых есть placeholder

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder]'),function(_in){
 _in.addEventListener('input',function(){
   this.placeholder = '';
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="pl01" >
<input type="text" placeholder="pl02" >
<input type="text" placeholder="pl03" >
<input type="text" placeholder="pl04" >
<input type="text" placeholder="pl05" >
```